# Changing the transaction isolation level in the TransactedReceiveScope activities

Tags: workflow-foundation, appfabric

Because we have locking problems in the database we would like to change the [`TransactedReceiveScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activities.transactedreceivescope.aspx) isolation level from `Serializable` to `ReadCommitted`. We have done this using a [`ServiceBehavior`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.aspx) extension:

```cs
 public class ReadCommittedServiceBehaviour : BehaviorExtensionElement ,IServiceBehavior
{

        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters) { }
        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {
            serviceDescription.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceBehaviorAttribute() { TransactionIsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted });
        }
        public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase) {}
        public override Type BehaviorType
        {
            get { return typeof(ReadCommittedServiceBehaviour); }
        }

        protected override object CreateBehavior()
        {
            return new ReadCommittedServiceBehaviour();
        }
}
```

What I want to know is... is this a good idea at AppFabric level? I am worried about the instance creation in the persistence database.

Thanks

Comment: Hard to say for sure but I expect you will probably be ok.  I doubt that we tested this isolation level.

Comment: I think this is important, we receive a lot of messages in parallel and we have had locking problems. Maybe the isolation level of the transacted receive scope should be configurable as is in the TransactionScope.

Ron, are you recovered?

Comment: Not recovered, just trying to keep my head in the game.